# Deleted a repo now having serious issues re commiting to a fresh new repo I created

Tags: linux, git, github, command-line-interface

I'm relatively new to the whole github thing. So, I deleted a repo from my github and then I'm to re commit on a new repo I created but it still recognizes the old repo it was linked to, so each time I say commit, it keeps saying "There's nothing to commit" meanwhile, the github page that's linked to the repo gives a 404 which is because the repo its linked to was deleted however the CLI still recognizes it, is there a way I can fix this.

**The aim is to start afresh, like, since I have deleted the repo on Github, I want to re create it, recommit, etc but it seems the past history is still being recognized.**

Comment: You might try editing your question to contain actual commands you are entering and messages you are receiving in return. As it stands, I can't follow it.

Comment: Are you using the command line or GitHub for Windows?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your local clone to work with the new repository. For that first remove the link to the old repo,

```
$ git remote remove origin
```

and then add the new repository,

```
$ git remote add origin -f <repo url>
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to start over with your new repo is

```
git clone <URL for your new repo>
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, a quick clarification

- A commit is local to your project, so indeed making a new commit is pointless, even if you have deleted your old remote repository.
- A push is effective on the server side, so I suppose this is where you will have some trouble with your new remote Github project, like a "fatal: repository not found".

So you have two options :

1) You start by cloning your new repository with :

```
git clone https://github.com/your_username/your_project.git.
```

And then you will be able to commit and then push but you will have to move your source code to this project.

2) If you want to keep your old "still linked" project, I'd effectively suggest to start fresh by removing your local .git folder, initialize a new one and then make a commit and a push to your new Github project.

Something like :

```
rm -rf .git
git init
git remote add origin https://github.com/your_username/your_project.git
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
git push origin master
```